# Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения Это запрещено, когда вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >=

Tags: sql-server, триггер

При добавление записи в таблицу, первая запись добавляется, а при добавлении второй выдает, что "вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения". На таблице висит триггер

```
    USE [ERP]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурнаПрих]    Script Date: 09.05.2016 18:08:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурнаПрих] 
ON [dbo].[Заявка]
FOR insert
AS 
DECLARE @V_Puti nvarchar(50);
SET @V_Puti = 'В пути';
SET nocount on
while (Select Дата_поступления From Заявка) >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
begin
Update Заявка Set Статус=@V_Puti where [№-заявки] in(select [№-заявки] from inserted)
END
```

Comment: Может нельзя использовать запрос таким образом в цикле `while`. Помнится нужна была куда более громоздкая конструкция. Конечно с тех пор может что и поменялось. Но после вставки второй записи запрос выдаст две строки, а сравнивать сервер может только одно значение за раз, о чём и сообщает.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятна логика запроса в while - в зависимости от того, что вы хотите получить, можно использовать такие варианты:

```
while (Select max(Дата_поступления) From Заявка) >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
```

или

```
while (Select min(Дата_поступления) From Заявка) >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
```

или

```
while exists (Select Дата_поступления From Заявка 
              where  Дата_поступления >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
```

ну и т.д.